# Merge and synonymise the "[Previews]"

Tags: support, retag-request, meta, synonym-request

Meta has three preview tags:

1. [preview](/questions/tagged/preview)

   > Live render of the post as you are writing it.
2. [markdown-preview](/questions/tagged/markdown-preview)

   > Questions about the live Markdown preview of posts as they're being typed.
3. [question-preview](/questions/tagged/question-preview)

   > The question preview is a rendered version of your question shown on the question editing page below the textarea where questions are typed in. It allows users to check for formatting issues and proofread before submitting.

I believe that these are all identical; or, at least, the semantic differences are so minor as to leave such a large amount of ambiguity that the difference essentially becomes meaningless.

They should all be merged into [preview](/questions/tagged/preview) or, possibly, a new tag [post-preview](/questions/tagged/post-preview) to combine all possible meanings into one.